# perl count line in double looping, if match regular expression plus 1

Tags: regex, perl, logic

I open a file by putting the line to an array. Inside this file based on the regular expression that contains a duplicate value. If the regular expression is a match I want to count it. The regular expression may look like this 
`$b =~ /\/([^\/]+)@@/`. I want to match `$1` value.

```
    my @array = do 
{
    open my $FH, '<', 'abc.txt' or die 'unable to open the file\n';
    <$FH>;
};
```

Below is the way I do, it will get the same line in my file. Thank for help.

```
 foreach my $b (@array)
{
    $conflictTemp = 0;
    $b =~ /\/([^\/]+)@@/;
    $b = $1;
    #print "$b\n";
    foreach my $c (@array)
    {
        $c =~ /\/([^\/]+)@@/;
        $c = $1;

        if($b eq $c)
        {   
            $conflictTemp ++;
            #print "$b , $c \n"
            #if($conflictTemp > 1)
            #{
            #   $conflict ++;
            #}
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the some sample data, two sentences are duplicates

```
/a/b/c/d/code/Debug/atlantis_digital/c/d/code/Debug/atlantis_digital.map@@/main/place.09/2

/a/b/c/d/code/C5537_mem_map.cmd@@/main/place.09/0

/a/b/c/d/code/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.prefs@@/main/4

/a/b/c/d/code/.project_initial@@/main/2

/a/b/c/d/code/.project@@/main/CSS5/5

/a/b/c/d/code/.cproject@@/main/CSS5/10

/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtproject@@/main/place.09/0

/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtproject@@/main/place.09/0

/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtbuild_initial@@/main/2

/a/b/c/d/code/.**cdtbuild@@**/main/CSS5/2

/a/b/c/d/code/.**cdtbuild@@**/main/CSS5/2

/a/b/c/d/code/.ccsproject@@/main/CSS5/3
```

Comment: Some sample data and desired output will make this question easier to answer. Also - single char variable names are nasty.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to iterate each element of the array, select some data via pattern match, and then count dupes. Is that correct?

Comment: yes Im trying to achieve this based on the pattern.

Comment: And the desired output given the above? Just flagging those two lines as 'duplicates'?

Comment: that just an example, above example,  **cdtproject** is also as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to iterate each element of the array, select some data via pattern match, and then count dupes. Is that correct?

Would it not be easier to:

```
my %count_of; 
while ( <$FH> ) {
   my (  $val ) = /\/([^\/]+)@@/;
   $count_of{$val}++; 
}
```

And then, for the variables that have more than one (e.g. there's a duplicate):

```
print join "\n", grep { $count_of{$_} > 1 } keys %count_of;
```

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to play 'spot the dupe':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen; 
my $match = qr/\/([^\/]+)@@/;
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $value ) = m/$match/ or next; 
    print if $seen{$value}++; 
}

__DATA__
/a/b/c/d/code/Debug/atlantis_digital/c/d/code/Debug/atlantis_digital.map@@/main/place.09/2
/a/b/c/d/code/C5537_mem_map.cmd@@/main/place.09/0
/a/b/c/d/code/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.prefs@@/main/4
/a/b/c/d/code/.project_initial@@/main/2
/a/b/c/d/code/.project@@/main/CSS5/5
/a/b/c/d/code/.cproject@@/main/CSS5/10
/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtproject@@/main/place.09/0
/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtproject@@/main/place.09/0
/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtbuild_initial@@/main/2
/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtbuild@@/main/CSS5/2
/a/b/c/d/code/.cdtbuild@@/main/CSS5/2
/a/b/c/d/code/.ccsproject@@/main/CSS5/3
```

Comment: use of uninitialized calue $val in hash element of project2.pl like 10, <$FH> wht is this error mean

Comment: Means you have a line that doesn't match. Add an `or next` after the match (code edited).

Comment: thx, my file contain space, i think it should be chomp. May be this is the easier way to do that. 
May i know why before variable my contain %

Comment: Because `%seen` is a hash, that lets you store key-values. Don't need `chomp` here, space is valid within a hash key.

Comment: Am i correct? if we are using hash, the result will only show once? why do not use array ?

Comment: may i know how to use double looping loop through my list to count the same line

Comment: If you can explain what you _actually want_ then I can give you a more specific answer. Looping twice is unnecessary. If you want a count, you can `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%seen;`

Comment: i see, because double looping is the concept that i able to think. I'm new for perl, just a week.

Comment: We still can't give you an answer, without knowing what your desired result actually is. Because your code as it stands - doesn't work. So to 'fix' it, we need to know what a correct output would look like.

Comment: your example is get the result i want.

Comment: Then double-looping is an awful solution to the problem. Familiarise yourself with a hash - they're really awesome, and explained in [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Comment: by using above hash answer, how should we display the same line number?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by the previous answer - I just want to offer an alternate flavour that;

- Spells out the regex
- Uses the `%seen` hash to record the line the pattern first appears; to enable
- slightly more detailed reporting

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;

my $regex = qr/
                \/             # A literal slash followed by
                (              # Capture to $1 ...
                   [^\/]+      #    ... anything that's not a slash
                )              # close capture to $1
                @@             # Must be immdiately followed by literal @@
            /x;

my %line_num ;
while (<>) {
    next unless /$regex/ ;
    my $pattern = $1 ;
    if ( $line_num{ $pattern } )  {
        say "'$pattern' appears on lines ", $line_num{ $pattern }, " and $." ;
        next ;
    }
    $line_num{ $pattern } = $. ;   # Record the line number
}

# Ran on data above will produce;
# '.cdtproject' appears on lines 7 and 8
# '.cdtbuild' appears on lines 10 and 11
```

Comment: may i know how to use double looping loop through my list to count the same line

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but if its how to run it, the script reads on STDIN and writes on STDOUT so, if your data is in a file called `in.txt`, and the script called `same.pl` you can do this `./same.pl in.txt` or `cat in.txt | ./same.pl`